# In windows 7, how to check from command-line if the wifi hardware switch is on or off?

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, switch, wmic

**In windows 7, how to check from command-line if the wifi hardware switch is on or off ?**

I will show you what happens when you toggle the hardware switch so that you may understand what exactly I am looking for.

Click on `Start > Run > mblctr` . This will launch the windows mobility center.

When the hardware switch is **ON** , the `turn wireless off(or on)` button will be clickable
 [image: turn wireless off]

Similarly, when the hardware switch is **OFF**, the `turn wireless on(or off)` button is greyed out. [image]

Here is one of my [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o97s2h2oLs4) where you can see the simulation

I have referred to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/820856/how-to-turn-wireless-on-off-from-command-line-on-windows-7) question , but the person is asking how to switch it from on to off. I just want to know how to check the status.

I have also seen checked out commands like `netsh interface show interface` 
but this shows whether the adapter is disabled or enabled.

Please help.

Comment: I think this can be done only using an `inferential` method rather than a direct method of finding out the status of the switch. In my case when I push the switch `OFF` my wireless says `Not Connected` **AND** my bluetooth network is `OFF`. So when these two conditions are met, you can infer that the switch is in `OFF` position

Comment: I have checked out the mobility center greyed out button in other laptops as well. Also if you see my video, IntelProset wireless tools, is also able to detect it(not very accurately) but still it detects.